# How do I create webgarden in webfarm

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using asp.net 4.0 with C# and my application is hosted on web farm which consist 2 sever with load balancer now I want to create web garden on each server to assign multiple process for application (To enhance application perfomance). Is it possible to create web garden inside webfarm.If yes then what changes I need to do, alll asp.net controls and state mgmtlike session application, caching woking fine or i need to do some setting for that Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the moment that you have web farm, the web garden must work with out any issue.

**Web Farm** is when you add 2 or more computers to run actually the same content.

**Web garder** is when you add on one computer 2 or more working process for the same application.

What you need to take care is the synchronization of the data. The Data must be the same on both computers, and on every working process. From the moment that you have all ready web farm I suppose that you use session on database that is common to both computers, so the same session is going to be used on web garden.

Also I suppose that if you use database, this is shared for the 2 computers, and you take care with the synchronization when you write data.

The synhronization is done inside a thread using the lock, inside a web garden using the mutex, and inside the web farm + web garden using a common mutex file name among computers, or some part of the database.

If you not write any data, then you do not need other synchronization other than the common session database. All the extra thinks that you have to take care here is the common data.

### Session on InProc

If you use Inproc session then the session is keeped on the memory on each computer.

Now if the load balance take care to send all the calls from the same user to the same computer it will work.

If not load balance take case to send all calls from the same user to the same computer then as you understand the same user can possible have two different session data, one on each computer, and because the session is keeped on same cookie name you probably have a mess with the session.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, we are using sql for session, but I have one question,for web form if I used session inproc, it will work or not?

Comment: @Areeb I replay to the answer. I user web garden and the hard think is the synchronizations among pools. The problem is that is hard to debug and locate the issues and you need to design and think where you need them. All our issues appears with the multi user on the web, and we can't see this issue on develop computer, at least as we have it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS 6, then this [article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/659f2e2c-a58b-4770-833b-df96cabe569e.mspx?mfr=true) will help you configure a Web Garden.

> In IIS 6.0 worker process isolation mode, application pools enhance
>   Web site or application reliability by isolating applications and the
>   worker processes that service those applications. For even greater
>   reliability, you can configure an application pool to be supported by
>   multiple worker processes. An application pool that uses more than one
>   worker process is called a Web garden. The worker processes in a Web
>   garden share the requests that arrive for that particular application
>   pool. If a worker process fails, another worker process can continue
>   to process requests.

If you are using IIS 7, this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0#webGarden) will help you configure a Web Garden.

Comment: Nice article it helps lot but I want to know I already have web farm for this application if I create webgarden then is their any drawback or limitation for application